# Spring/Hibernate/Transaction synchronization issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, deadlock

I have a service that returns a persisted Schedule object based on an input: date.  I have multiple threads calling this method and I would like to ensure uniqueness.  I don't want to catch a constraint violation and give any user an error.  What I need is: if one thread calls the method and a Schedule object doesn't exist for that date, that thread creates it and the other threads wait.  Before I have been using Spring, just plain Hibernate in my web applicaiton I have done it the following way:

I've used a ManagedSessionContext with hibernate.  I was starting a transaction in the beginning of each web request and commiting it in the end. For the synchronized blocks I've commited the current transaction right away in a synchronized block and started a new one to finish the request. My isolation level was READ_COMMITED and it worked great.

```
public synchronized Schedule getSchedule(Date date) {
  Schedule schedule = dao.getSchedule(date);
  if (schedule == null) {
    schedule = createSchedule(date);
    dao.save(schedule);
    HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().begin();

  }
  return schedule;
}
```

Now I am using Spring with this project and I'm using aop for transaction management.  I have removed the manual transaction code.  I'm testing with multiple threads and I'm getting a deadlock
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

My Transaction AOP:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
      <tx:attributes >
      <tx:method name="getSchedule" isolation="SERIALIZABLE" />
      <tx:method name="*" />
      </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Autowire
private HibernateTransactionManager txManager;
```

Wrap the method body with:

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
def.setName("transactionName");
def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
TransactionStatus ts = txManager.getTransaction(def);

//Body Code

txManager.commit(ts);
```